# Must hit refresh button to load text_area with correct formatting, Javascript and Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, document-ready

I'm using CKeditor https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails. in a Rails 4 app.

I have it working, however, I have to hit the refresh button on the page where the WYSIWYG is set up. In my application.js file I have this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { //this line was my attempt to fix the problem
$('.ckeditor').ckeditor({
  // optional config
});
}); //and this one which is just closing the function
```

What I mean is I get to the page where WYSIWYG should be and all that shows is a small text_area. When I hit the refresh button, the WYSIWYG shows up.  I thought the document.ready function would fix it but apparently not. any idea why?

my rails code snippet in the view template is this:

```
<%= f.text_area  :description, :class => 'ckeditor' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var ready;
ready = function() {  
  $('.ckeditor').ckeditor({
    // optional config
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(window).load(ready);
```

I guess that your page is loaded via AJAX or you using Turbolinks, do you?

Comment: WOW! It works!!! Thanks a bunch! Now I just hope that didn't break anything. ha. Seeems like everything I do something gets broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing it on $(window).load

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Turbolinks, as mentioned above. The solution can be found here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#opting-out-of-turbolinks

You must include turbolinks and do a couple things mentioned in the link above.